# Name of a symmetric matrix with zeroes in the diagonal

Tags: matrix, diagonal

I am looking for a term that can be used for a matrix with the diagonal line equal to zeros and the upper and lower triangles are symmetric.

for example if I have a matrix of size 5 by 5 the matrix will be as following:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 0 5 6 7
2 5 0 8 9
3 6 8 0 10
4 7 9 10 0
```

Is there a term for this matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right forum for this question...but what you are looking for is a hollow symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hollow symmetric matrix. Hollow means the main diagonal has all zeroes. Symmetric means the upper triangle and lower triangle are "equal."

Answer (score 0):

It is a **Zero-diagonal-symmetric-matrice**, also known as **hollow symmetric** (or hermitian) matrice.

Reference here - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79779/properties-of-zero-diagonal-symmetric-matrices

Answer (score 0):

There is also an entry for Hollow Matrix
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_matrix)

Comment: Hollow matrices aren't necessarily symmetric.

Comment: @Victor C.True. That is what I get for not reading the entire question !

Comment: Well, you still read half of it, which is more than a lot of people do :)